# Embed HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a chunk of HTML which I'd like to add to a document at run time.

How do I embed the HTML within the JS file?

```
var p = document.createElement("div");
p.innerHTML = '<div>  MY HTML  
               <some element>  </some element>
               <some element>  </some element>
               </div>'
```

The problem is that my HTML is multiline; how do I add the newline chars within a JS string?

Comment: You don't want the <br/> tags do you?

Comment: Why do you care if your HTML is multiline?  The browser will be stripping out the whitespace anyway.

Comment: @Thomas: Ever tried editing a large chunk of HTML (or anything else for that matter) that is place all on one line.

Answer (score 2):

you can use backslash character to ignore end of line in JavaScript strings.

http://www.componentart.com/BLOGS/jovan/archive/2007/10/17/multiline-strings-in-javascript.aspx